# Strange characters appearing with alpha and beta

Tags: math-mode, characters, python, pattern

I used a python regex file to edit a section of LaTex that contained alpha and beta. Here it is:

```
Jacobi
  & $\JacobiP{\alpha}{\beta}{n}@{x}$
    \MarkDefn[P z 3 - jacobi]{$\JacobiP{\alpha}{\beta}{n}@{x}$}{Jacobi polynomial}%
  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(1 - x)^{\alpha} (1 + x)^{\beta}$
  & $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, &\text{$n = 0$} \end{cases}$
  & $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, & \text{$n = 0$}\end{cases}$
  & $\dfrac{\pochhammer{n+\alpha+\beta+1}{n}}{2^n n!}$
  & $\dfrac{n (\alpha-\beta)}{2n+\alpha+\beta}$
  & $\alpha,\beta > -1$
```

The result after editing it with regex is as follows:

```
\Jacobi\JacobiP{^Glpha}{^Heta}{n}@{x}(-1,1)(1-x)^{^Glpha}(1+x)^{^Heta}^Hegin{cases}\ifrac{2^{^Glpha+^Heta+1}\EulerGamma@{^Glpha+1}\EulerGamma@{^Heta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{^Glpha+^Heta+2}},                                                         ext{n=0}\end{cases}^Hegin{cases}\ifrac{2^{^Glpha+^Heta+1}\EulerGamma@{^Glpha+1}\EulerGamma@{^Heta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{^Glpha+^Heta+2}},                            ext{n=0}\end{cases}\dfrac{\pochhammer{n+^Glpha+^Heta+1}{n}}{2^nn!}\dfrac{n(^Glpha-^Heta)}{2n+^Glpha+^Heta}^Glpha,^Heta>-1\int_{-1}^{1}\JacobiP{^Glpha}{^Heta}{n}@{x}\JacobiP{^Glpha}{^Heta}{m}@{x}(1-x)^{^Glpha}(1+x)^{^Heta}dx=0
```

It is supposed to be on one line. I am unable to understand why all the B's from the beta's became '^H' and why the first character of 'alpha' became '^G'. In addition, why is there a huge space before ending the case?

EDIT- here is my python code that is using regex:

```
def split(content):
    count = 1
    for m in re.finditer(r'(?s)(\\\[-16pt]\n)(.*?)(\n *\\\\\n\\thinhline)', content):
       if count == 1:
           jacobi =  m.group(2) + "&"
           content  = re.sub(r'(?s)(\\\[-16pt]\nJacobi\n)(.*?)(\n *\\\\\n\\thinhline)',components(jacobi),content)
def components(content):
    formula =function.split("&")
    range = formula[2]
    a = "-1"
    b = "1"
    formula[8] = re.sub("n","m",formula[1])
    x = function + "\n" + "$$\int_{" + a + "}+{" + b + "}" + formula[1] + formula[8] + formula[3] + "dx$$=0"
    x = x.replace('\n','')
    x = x.replace('\MarkDefn','')
    x = x.replace('\MarkDefm','')
    x = x.replace('$', '')
    x = x.replace('&','')
    x = x.replace(' ','')
    return x
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,thank you.

Comment: presumably if the regex replace messed up the file there was an error in the regex or its replacement text, but since you showed neither it's hard to guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my regex takes the first section of code directly and just re-organizes it, in the file the '^H' and '^G' are highlighted blue, like they're not even strings at all.

Comment: I would assume you have turned `\text` into `tab ext`  as `\t` is the tab character escape in most C-like string syntax, but how you did that without seeing the code. presumably the other `\ ` have been mis-interpreted as string escapes giving the control characters that you show,

Comment: You have shown the input and output to a program and asking people to debug the unshown program that produced the output without any information about the program or the intended output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, I edited it and added my program.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Python, not TeX.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have shown no code this is debugging in the dark.

However I would guess that you put the latex into a python string while forgetting to quote `\` as `\\`.

`\` followed by a single letter is a string escape

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

so `\a` is BELL that is control-g ^G

`\t` is TAB

etc.

Comment: I have added my code, please help me out here.

Comment: @shr It is a python error unrelated to TeX, so off topic here but you need `\\ ` to put `\ ` into a normal python string.

Comment: I added 'x = x.replace("\","\\")' in components to fix the problem but I'm getting an error that says : 'SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character'. I know this is more of a python question, so if you don't know that's fine!